# C++ regular expressions on large strings

Tags: c++, regex

I need to check whether a certain pattern occurs at the beginning of a large string (say on the order of a gigabyte), and I'm wondering whether C++ standard library regular expressions are suitable.

I tried `regex_search` with `^` at the start of the pattern, and `regex_match` with `.*` at the end of the pattern, but both crash when the string gets up to a few tens of megabytes.

Is there some trick I should be using, or is it the case that C++ regular expressions are not the right tool for large strings?

For the test case, I used a string consisting entirely of `"aaaaaa..."` and a regular expression consisting of either `"^aaa"` or `"aaa.*"` to keep it simple. I tested on Microsoft C++; whatever solution I end up with has to work on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Technically, simple cases such as `.*` can be optimized to use O(1) memory. It might be the case that the problem is elsewhere. You might want to include the offending regex into the question.

Comment: @nhahtdh Right, such cases can be so optimised, but it seems they aren't at least in Microsoft's implementation. Okay, added.

Comment: The problem with `regex_search` of an anchored regex is that the anchor may match following a newline in the string. That shouldn't matter if the regex actually matches at the beginning of the string, but it means that if the pattern does not match, the rest of the string can be searched for an instance of the pattern following a newline. Use `match_continuous` to really anchor. (This shouldn't apply as the problem is stated, but then the long input string shouldn't cause a crash either. Perhaps you need to paste actually executable code.)

Comment: @rici `match_continuous` instead of `^` does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @rwallace: The question you have here is quite ill-defined. You might want to clarify it and post your own answer, or just delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is limit the range of your search using iterators like this example that only checks upto the first 100 characters:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s(1024 * 1024 * 1024, 'a');

    std::regex e("^aaa");

    // limit the range of your search using iterators
    if(std::regex_search(s.begin(), s.begin() + 100, e)) // 100 max
    {
        std::cout << "yes\n";
    }

}
```

Obviously the number of characters you allow is determined by the maximum size of a possible match.